# Reflectively instantiating classes in another package, declared with default access in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I tried to instantiate a class that was declared with default access, in another package reflectively and received this error:

Class IOTest can not access a member of class com.BinspireD.core.model.DataNodeImpl with modifiers "public".

It this possible (to instantiate a class using reflection in a different package, with package private access)?

How would I properly go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution to these types of problems is as follows:

- Think long and hard about what you're trying to do.  Is it really necessary?
- Chastise yourself with a small flail if you decide that it is.
- Cheat.  Check out the Javadoc for `java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject`.

Comment: And avoid `Class.newInstance` *even more* than other reflection methods.

Comment: You forget step #4.  Hand the flail to your co-workers so that they can chastise you as well.